# Gradle Self Dependency Resolution

Tags: java, maven, gradle, gradle-dependencies

First of all, sorry for the kinda specific question and the lack of an MCVE, which is due to the nature of artifact publishing causing this problem.

A project having a dependency on itself may sound like it doesn't make sense, but I am sure it will after reading the explanation below.

---

I am trying to bootstrap a code generator, that uses an earlier version of itself to generate part of its Java code. The code generator itself works, and so does the Gradle plugin that I have written for it. The problem is that the plugin requires specifying a dependency to declare which version of my tool to use. So the project has a dependency on itself (albeit an older version).

The `build.gradle` of the tool looks like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'de.clashsoft.gentreesrc-gradle' version '1.2.3'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

// name = 'gentreesrc' (settings.gradle)
version = '0.3.1'
group   = 'de.clashsoft'

repositories {
    // where the artifact is published
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    // the configuration added by the plugin
    gentreesrc group: 'de.clashsoft', name: 'gentreesrc', version: '0.3.1'
}

// publishing configuration...
```

Now, the plugin creates the `gentreesrc` configuration (without any fancy extras), and a task named `gentreesrcJava`:

```
task gentreesrcJava(type: JavaExec) {
    // ...
    classpath = configurations.gentreesrc
    main = 'de.clashsoft.gentreesrc.Main'
    // ...
}
```

When I try to run this task on my tool project, I get the error:

```
> Task :gentreesrcJava FAILED

Error: Could not find or load main class de.clashsoft.gentreesrc.Main
```

I have tracked the problem down to the resolution of my `gentreesrc` dependency: instead of resolving it to the published artifact on jcenter, it uses the non-existing artifact in `build/libs/`, as evident by this output:

```
/Users/me/projectDir/build/libs/gentreesrc-0.3.1.jar
/Users/me/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.antlr/antlr4-runtime/4.7.2/e27d8ab4f984f9d186f54da984a6ab1cccac755e/antlr4-runtime-4.7.2.jar
/Users/me/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.antlr/ST4/4.1/467d508be07a542ad0a68ffcaed2d561c5fb2e0c/ST4-4.1.jar
/Users/me/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.4/c51c00206bb913cd8612b24abd9fa98ae89719b1/commons-cli-1.4.jar
/Users/me/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.antlr/antlr-runtime/3.5.2/cd9cd41361c155f3af0f653009dcecb08d8b4afd/antlr-runtime-3.5.2.jar
```

of the following addition to `build.gradle`:

```
gentreesrcJava.doFirst {
    gentreesrcJava.classpath.each { println it }
}
```

Interestingly, this also happens when I change the `version = '0.3.1'` part to `version = '0.4.0'` (the first line of the classpath output changes to `/Users/me/projectDir/build/libs/gentreesrc-0.4.0.jar`).
However, writing `version = '0.2.0'` causes no issues (the build does not fail and works as expected).

---

Now to the actual question: **why does Gradle resolve the dependency the way it does (to the artifact in `build/libs/`)?** Is there a way to ignore this artifact and force resolution via jcenter?

Comment: Have you tried using artifact classifiers? just publish your artifacts with an additional classifier and try to use it as the older version dependency... Not sure if it'll work, but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 1):

Gradle will by default match binary dependencies with project identifiers and do regular conflict resolution.

So if your plugin is a higher version of the same `group:name`, then you will not be able to resolve an older version from an external repository.
The fact that it works with `0.2.0` is weird. Any chance you also modified the `group` or `name`?

For workarounds, see the [Gradle issue tracker](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/7706).

Comment: Thanks, the workaround behind the link solved the issue. Perhaps you should include it in your answer in case the link breaks. I did not modify group or name since the project started.